# Is There A Technical Reason SystemVerilog Cannot Pass Module Name as Parameter?

Tags: system-verilog

I want to do something like this:

```
module BusinessLogicVersion_1(clk, rst, d, q);
// Erudite business logic goes here
endmodule

module BusinessLogicVersion_2(clk, rst, d, q);
// Different implementation of same interface.
endmodule

// Then, when instantiating the module that requires an implementation of whatever interface,
// I want to do something like this:
ModuleXyz #(
    .business_logic(BusinessLogicVersion_2) // <--- Pass an implementation of an interface as parameter
) (.clk(clk), .rst(rst), ...);
```

I have tried to find ways to do this, and from what I've read SV does not allow it.

My question is:

Is there a technical reason why this shouldn't be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, nothing is technically impossible in software given enough time, space and money! StackOverflow is not the forum for *why* kinds of questions.

SystemVerilog has a different approaches that implements what you are looking for. One way is  called a **configuration** (See section *33. Configuring the contents of a design* in the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595)).

For your case, what you would do is compile different versions of same module name `ModuleXyz` into different libraries and then use either command line options or a `config` block that selects which version to be selected for different instances. I would look at the LRM for examples.

The other method is using a _generate construct to select different modules you want instantiated. See section *27. Generate constructs*. This is simpler, but less flexible since you have to know upfront which versions are available.

```
case(VERSION):
1: BusinessLogicVersion_1 inst (clk, rst, d, q);
2: BusinessLogicVersion_2 inst (clk, rst, d, q);
default: $error("Version does not exist");
endcase
```

Comment: The question does not ask why. It only asks whether a technical reason exists. What I really want to know is whether this is a reasonable feature to ask for in the future, which is a perfectly valid question for a forum where it's appropriate to discuss languages.

Comment: @JamesStrieter "Is there a technical reason why this shouldn't be possible?" is certainly a 'Why' question. My answer states that what you want to do **is** possible in SystemVerilog using a conceptually different approach. Discussions about what alternatives  might be possible is generally consider opinion based and off-topic for StackOverflow. You might try asking here https://verificationacademy.com/forums/systemverilog/all

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to do some kind of dependency injection, where the modules you're passing in are supposed to be different strategies. Also, I see from your profile that you're familiar with C++, so I'll try to map what you're trying to do onto that language. (Beware of gross simplifications or not-so-accurate analogies.)

A SystemVerilog `module` is akin to a C++ `class`. By passing a module name to you `ModuleXyz`, you're trying to do something like pass a class as a function argument in C++. This isn't possible in that language either. You generally pass instances of classes.

In order to pass an instance of a class, you'd need to first construct it. This would mean passing it your desired constructor arguments. Your module has ports, which are conceptually similar to a class's constructor arguments. When you instantiate a module, you connect its ports.

In your example, I'm guessing you would like to pass in the type of module that `ModuleXyz` should instantiate inside. In C++ you would generally pass a factory object, which knows how to construct the object you need, with the constructor arguments you want. This pattern isn't possible with modules, as only "direct" instantiation is allowed.

As @dave_59 pointed out, switching out module types is done using `configurations`. It's sort of like doing dynamic loading of different shared libraries, to switch out the implementations.

If your simulator doesn't support configurations (as language constructs), it will usually provide compile switches that allow you to implement something similar. It will compile different versions of the module, but you will be able to choose which one gets "linked".

If you really, really need to use dependency injection, I'd suggest you try to migrate your code from trying to pass modules, to passing `interfaces`. It is possible to pass **instances** of those around. Just remember, that you'll be passing already constructed instances, not types.

Comment: I prefer not to pass an instance. If we're going to compare to a C-like language, perhaps it's better to say I want to pass a constructor. In Python, for instance, you can pass a constructor without calling the constructor. Passing around instances of interfaces might be a step in the right direction, but what I really want to do is more like passing in a function handle, in this case a constructor, and have that constructor be called when the compiler arrives at the module instantiation.

Comment: There is a slight difference between the answer as it now stands and the question. I already know that what I want to do is not possible presently. I'm asking whether there is a technical reason why passing in a constructor, without calling it, could not be done. I am wondering whether the language could be updated to support this feature.

Comment: 1. StackOverflow is probably not the right place to ask this. I did it a couple of times as well for other language features and never really got anywhere.
2. This is not the way most people would code, so not much drive. Also, there are alternatives to implement what you want, so this would be another way of achieving the same result. SV is full of redundancy already.
3. An anecdote on the likeliness of such a thing being added: it took I don't know how many years of discussions about function call chaining, to figure out whether it can be added at all.